# Epoch taking too long to complete

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am trying to apply U-net for image segmentation on CT scans. My dataset consists of about 8,000 images for train and 506 images for validation. I have followed [this tutorial](https://github.com/nikhilroxtomar/UNET-Segmentation-on-CT-Scan-Images-in-TensorFlow-2.0), step by step, but my training time is taking too long for a single epoch, 29 hours to be precise. What could I have done wrong?

```
import os
os.environ["TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL"] = "2"
import numpy as np
import cv2
from glob import glob
from sklearn.utils import shuffle
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint, CSVLogger, ReduceLROnPlateau, EarlyStopping, TensorBoard
from tensorflow.python.keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.python.keras.metrics import Recall, Precision
from model import build_unet
from metrics import dice_loss, dice_coef, iou

H = 512
W = 512

def create_dir(path):
    """ Create a directory. """
    if not os.path.exists(path):
        os.makedirs(path)

def shuffling(x, y):
    x, y = shuffle(x, y, random_state=42)
    return x, y

def load_data(path):
    x = sorted(glob(os.path.join(path, "image", "*.jpg")))
    y = sorted(glob(os.path.join(path, "mask", "*.jpg")))
    return x, y

def read_image(path):
    path = path.decode()
    x = cv2.imread(path, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
    x = x/255.0
    x = x.astype(np.float32)
    return x

def read_mask(path):
    path = path.decode()
    x = cv2.imread(path, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    x = x/255.0
    x = x > 0.5
    x = x.astype(np.float32)
    x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=-1)
    return x

def tf_parse(x, y):
    def _parse(x, y):
        x = read_image(x)
        y = read_mask(y)
        return x, y

    x, y = tf.numpy_function(_parse, [x, y], [tf.float32, tf.float32])
    x.set_shape([H, W, 3])
    y.set_shape([H, W, 1])
    return x, y

def tf_dataset(x, y, batch=8):
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x, y))
    dataset = dataset.map(tf_parse)
    dataset = dataset.batch(batch)
    dataset = dataset.prefetch(10)
    return dataset


if __name__ == "__main__":
    """ Seeding """
    np.random.seed(42)
    tf.random.set_seed(42)

    """ Directory for storing files """
    create_dir("files")

    """ Hyperparameters """
    batch_size = 16
    lr = 1e-3
    num_epochs = 5
    model_path = os.path.join("files", "model.h5")
    csv_path = os.path.join("files", "data.csv")

    """ Dataset """
    dataset_path = os.path.join("new_data")
    train_path = os.path.join(dataset_path, "train")
    valid_path = os.path.join(dataset_path, "valid")

    train_x, train_y = load_data(train_path)
    train_x, train_y = shuffling(train_x, train_y)
    valid_x, valid_y = load_data(valid_path)

    print(f"Train: {len(train_x)} - {len(train_y)}")
    print(f"Valid: {len(valid_x)} - {len(valid_y)}")

    train_dataset = tf_dataset(train_x, train_y, batch=batch_size)
    valid_dataset = tf_dataset(valid_x, valid_y, batch=batch_size)

    """ Model """
    model = build_unet((H, W, 3))
    metrics = [dice_coef, iou, Recall(), Precision()]
    model.compile(loss=dice_loss, optimizer=Adam(lr), metrics=metrics)

    callbacks = [
        ModelCheckpoint(model_path, verbose=1, save_best_only=True),
        ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss', factor=0.1, patience=10, min_lr=1e-7, verbose=1),
        CSVLogger(csv_path),
        TensorBoard(),
        EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=50, restore_best_weights=False),
    ]

    model.fit(
        train_dataset,
        epochs=num_epochs,
        validation_data=valid_dataset,
        callbacks=callbacks,
        shuffle=False
    )
```

Comment: I do not know if this is useful but I have the following warnings : tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1934] Cannot dlopen some GPU libraries. Please make sure the missing libraries mentioned above are installed properly if you would like to use GPU.
tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:193] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX AVX2
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.

Comment: The code in the tutorial runs with approximately 45 minutes ETA, so i was wondering what problems could it be.

Comment: DO you have a GPU? If so, which one?

Comment: I have a nvidia gtx 1650, but i have been unable to determine how can I use it. Thanks! I must also mention that since i have vscode with python interpreter from microsoft store, i still haven't found out a way to use conda forge in the terminal

Comment: You need to install the right CUDA and cuDNN libraries, the messages about missing libraries tells you which ones are missing.

Comment: I install cuDNN 8.5.0.96 and CUDA 11.8 - according to https://spltech.co.uk/how-to-install-tensorflow-2-5-with-cuda-11-2-and-cudnn-8-1-for-windows-10/ but still getting the same error when i try to run len(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU') Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_110.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_110.dll not found. Where should i put these files?

Comment: The 110 probably means CUDA version 11.0, install this exact version and make sure the libraries are in the PATH environment variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just downloaded the files and trained the model. Each epoch took around 8:30 min, which sounds good.
There are some reasons that we may point out here. For instance

1. Not enough memory
2. Using only CPU
3. Using an old GPU
   You can check if your files are ok running the project in another environment like Google Colab or Kaggle. In both, you can enable the use of GPU.
   Running on these boxes, you can compare with your environment and get a better idea about what is not ok on your end.

Answer (score 0):

On my old running desktop, I experience the same issues before re-compile the Tensorflow API libraries find log indicates the missing libraries and located them.

For my very old desktop I added them and compile them.

1. C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.4\bin
2. C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing
   Toolkit\CUDA\v11.4\extras\CUPTI\lib64

Comment: This answer unfortunately makes no sense.

Comment: You asked about too a long time running epochs with errors returning no support libraries, asking to re-compile it again then I suggest you add target libraries into the paths.